# Reading a file in C and passing the contents to main()

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

I'm new to C.  I'm having an issue accessing the data read in from a file.  The idea behind what I'm trying to do is get a text file, read it in, create an array and set the contents of that array equal to the contents of the file (the characters).

Now, here is where I get confused. To manipulate `tStr` in the main method,  I need to be able to access its contents set in the read method.  If I try to access the `tStr` array in the main class, from my understanding, you wont be able to considering you have only set the size of it but passed no values into it.

If I want to edit the array `tStr` that should contain the contents of the text file how do i get that data from `readFile()` to `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define size 1000

    int readFile(char fn[], char tStr[]);

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        char tStr[size];
        return 0;
    }

    int readFile(char fn[], char tStr[])
    {
        FILE *fptr;
        char c;
        int i = 0;

        if ((fptr=fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL){
            printf("Error: unknown file %s\n", fn);
            exit(1);
        }

        while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
            tStr[i++] = c;

        tStr[i] = '\0';

        return i;   
    }
```

Comment: `char tStr[size];readFile("file.txt", tStr);`. also `char c;` change to `int c;` and add `fclose(fptr);`

Comment: You may want to *call* `readFile()` from `main` first. You have only declared and defined the function, not called it, so it will not do anything.

Comment: For a more useful error message written to the correct stream: `if((fptr = fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL) { perror(fn) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, there is good reason to be able to simply call a function to read a file and have the function return a pointer to an allocated array of strings holding the file's contents. This is especially true when you have no idea how long the file is. While you can pass a pointer, it would required a `***` argument to handle `realloc` changing the pointer address in the even of reallocation.

Declaring a function as `char **` and having it return a pointer to an allocated array is a standard way of handling this situation. Additionally, choosing some reasonable number of pointers to allocate initially and following a standard reallocation scheme (on `realloc`, allocate `2X` the number of current pointers) avoids costly and relatively expensive calls to `realloc` seen when calling `realloc` for each line in the file.

When you dynamically allocate memory, it is up to you to keep track of the memory, preserve a pointer to the start of the memory block (so you can `free` it), and `free` the memory when it is no longer needed.

The following puts all those puzzle pieces together in a short example. The example uses `getline` to read lines from the file and `strdup` (which allocates memory and copies) to copy lines read by `getline` into the array of strings. Let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NMAX 256

char **readtxtfile (char *fn, size_t *idx);
void prn_chararray (char **ca);
void free_chararray (char **ca);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t file_size = 0;   /* placeholders to be filled by readtxtfile */
    char *fn = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL;

    /* read each file into an array of strings,
    number of lines read, returned in file_size */
    char **file = readtxtfile (fn, &file_size);

    /* output number of lines read and from where  */
    printf ("\n read '%zu' lines from file: %s\n\n", file_size, fn ? fn : "stdin");

    /* simple print function */
    if (file) prn_chararray (file);

    /* simple free memory function */
    if (file) free_chararray (file);

    return 0;
}

char **readtxtfile (char *fn, size_t *idx)
{
    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* size of ln, 0 - getline decides  */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t nmax = NMAX;             /* check for reallocation           */
    char **array = NULL;            /* array to hold lines read         */
    FILE *fp = NULL;                /* file pointer to open file fn     */

    /* open / validate file or read stdin */
    if (fn) {
        if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.", __func__, fn);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else
        fp = stdin;

    /* allocate NMAX pointers to char* */
    if (!(array = calloc (NMAX, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read each line from stdin - dynamicallly allocated   */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

    array[*idx] = strdup (ln);  /* allocate/copy ln to array        */

        (*idx)++;                   /* increment value at index         */

        if (*idx == nmax) {         /* if lines exceed nmax, reallocate */
            char **tmp = realloc (array, nmax * 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: reallocation failed.\n", __func__);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE); /* or return NULL; */
            }
            array = tmp;
            nmax *= 2;
        }
    }

    if (ln) free (ln);              /* free memory allocated by getline */
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close open file descriptor       */

    return array;
}

/* print an array of character pointers. */
void prn_chararray (char **ca)
{
    register size_t n = 0;
    while (ca[n])
    {
        printf (" arr[%3zu]  %s\n", n, ca[n]);
        n++;
    }
}

/* free array of char* */
void free_chararray (char **ca)
{
    if (!ca) return;
    register size_t n = 0;
    while (ca[n])
        free (ca[n++]);
    free (ca);
}
```

**Output**

```
$ /bin/getline_readfile_function <~/tmp/fc-list-fonts-sorted-no-path.txt

 read '187' lines from file: stdin

 arr[  0]  andalemo.ttf: Andale Mono - Regular
 arr[  1]  arialbd.ttf: Arial - Bold
 arr[  2]  arialbi.ttf: Arial - Bold Italic
 arr[  3]  ariali.ttf: Arial - Italic
 arr[  4]  arialnbi.ttf: Arial
 arr[  5]  arialnb.ttf: Arial
 arr[  6]  arialni.ttf: Arial
 arr[  7]  arialn.ttf: Arial
 arr[  8]  arial.ttf: Arial - Regular
 arr[  9]  ARIALUNI.TTF: Arial Unicode MS - Regular
 arr[ 10]  ariblk.ttf: Arial
 arr[ 11]  Bailey Script Regular.ttf: Bailey Script - Regular
 arr[ 12]  Bailey_Script_Regular.ttf: Bailey Script - Regular
 arr[ 13]  Belwe Gotisch.ttf: Belwe Gotisch - Regular
 arr[ 14]  Belwe_Gotisch.ttf: Belwe Gotisch - Regular
<snip>
```

**Memory Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getline_readfile_function <~/tmp/fc-list-fonts-sorted-no-path.txt
==20259== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20259== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20259== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20259== Command: ./bin/getline_readfile_function
==20259==

 read '187' lines from file: stdin

 arr[  0]  andalemo.ttf: Andale Mono - Regular
 arr[  1]  arialbd.ttf: Arial - Bold
 arr[  2]  arialbi.ttf: Arial - Bold Italic
 arr[  3]  ariali.ttf: Arial - Italic
<snip>

==20259==
==20259== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20259==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20259==   total heap usage: 189 allocs, 189 frees, 9,831 bytes allocated
==20259==
==20259== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20259==
==20259== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20259== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

**Note:** if the pointer `fn` passed to `readtxtfile` is `NULL`, then input is read from `stdin`. (this just adds flexibility to the input routine) The call above could have just as easily been:

```
./bin/getline_readfile_function ~/tmp/fc-list-fonts-sorted-no-path.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `readFile` and pass it the files path and an array to be filled with the file content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define size 1000

    int readFile(char fn[], char tStr[]);

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        char tStr[size];
        readFile("file.txt",tStr);
        printf("%s", tStr);
        return 0;
    }

    int readFile(char fn[], char tStr[])
    {
        FILE *fptr;
        char c;
        int i = 0;

        if ((fptr=fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL){
            printf("Error: unknown file %s\n", fn);
            exit(1);
        }

        while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
            tStr[i++] = c;

        tStr[i] = '\0';

        return i;   
    }
```

Note that the array must be big enough for the file content or there will be undefined behaviour.

The normal c idiom when passing an array is to also pass an int or size_t parameter indicating the size of the buffer and only write that many chars to the buffer.

Also passing an already open `FILE*` might be better than passing the file path. To relieve the function of the burden of indicating file related errors.

Comment: You as well as the OP are not checking if `tStr` is exceeding its bounds. Furthermore the error message from `fopen` could be more informative, check the `strerror` function.

Comment: Agreed function is copied from OP question. I'm answering one specific question. That function could actually be omitted from my answer, as only main is changed.